# Mongoid; ERROR Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: not authorized for query

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-grape

I am creating an application using ruby/grape and mongoid. But when I try to create or find a document in any collection using mongoid, for example with `Admin.create` I get the following error:

```
ERROR Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: not authorized for query on databse.collection
```

I can log in to mongo console and create/find documents just fine with the credentials I use in mongoid.yml.

mongoid.yml:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: my_db
      hosts:
        - myhost:port
      username: db_user
      password: my_password
```

Answer (score 4):

You're format is off. Try this

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: my_db
      hosts:
        - myhost:port
      options:
        user: db_user
        password: my_password
```

Notice the `options` section and that `username` is `user`